# Light-weight web development editor

Tags: editor, web-development

I have just started using ubuntu and I want to continue developing my website however I realised notepad++ isn't Linux compatible and I was wondering is there something similar to notepadd++ that doesn't have that many features but has syntax highlighting. I know  ubuntu comes with one but I don't like the look and indenting of the text and how it responds. Thank to anyone who can help.

Comment: Take a look at [Kate](http://kate-editor.org/), or [Geany](http://www.geany.org/Main/HomePage).

Comment: They both have a disgusting layout which makes everything look crammed in, do you know any that have a text-editor layout but with syntax high-lighting?

Answer (score 0):

I personnally had the same problem before. What i suggest to you, find text editor that suits best for you, kate `sudo apt-get install kate` suits for me, and then just mount the ftp location to the nautilus or whatever file explorer you are using, and open the file from there and save to the same place too.

You can mount ftp in this way easy: write to the file-explorer path ftp://yourdomain.com/folder/. Should ask you your credentials after that and mount your ftp destination.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Emacs with web-mode is great for web development (in my opinion), and the key mappings are MUCH quicker and less strenuous than, for example, having to reach over to the arrow keys constantly.

Alternatively, Kate from KDE is quite good and has syntax highlighting for PHP, ASP, HTML, JavaScript...